# Bash Variable escape character

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to generate a url using a bunch of different variables however when I follow a variable with an underscore the variable after the underscore does not show up. However, if I put a space before the underscore then there is a space in the generated URL.  So my question is, is there an escape character for doing the sort of thing I have described?

Also code:

```
URL="$baseURL$BUILD/TorBrowserBundle-$BUILD-$OS$BIT _$LANG.zip"
```

The issue occurs in between $BIT and $LANG.

Comment: `URL="${baseURL}${BUILD}/TorBrowserBundle-${BUILD}-${OS}${BIT}_${LANG}.zip"`

Answer (score 1):

you can use ${}

so something like

```
URL="${baseURL}${BUILD}/TorBrowserBundle-${BUILD}-${OS}${BIT}_${LANG}.zip"
```

Comment: If you think that's the solution, you need accept it.